# Master composer.json to multiple apps

Tags: composer-php

Is there anyway I can config composer.json to install the project into a subfolder and maintain the composer.json in the root?

For example, if I do:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel apps/app1
```

I'll have the composer.json available at apps/app1, but what I want is to have composer.json into apps, this way I could composer update at apps and all apps under apps should be updated too.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Composer is a dependency manager and as such manages dependencies strictly on a per-project basis.

That said, you could easily write a bash script that loops over your projects and runs `composer update` on each one of them.

An example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in $(ls); do
    (cd $dir; composer update);
done
```

Comment: Why not executing composer in include path? Btw, **never** iterate over `ls` results. This is a common bad practice... What if filenames will contain specials chars like ` ` ? use `find -execdir` instead